how to solve "gradle failed resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0"
Android Studio の最新バージョンをダウンロードすると、「Gradle が com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0 を解決できませんでした」という解決方法が示されます。すべて試しましたが、何も役に立ちません。2022 バージョンの別のアプリケーションでも、すべてがダウンロードされます。何を知っておく必要がありますか?
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }  // добавляем JitPack
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/theartofdev/Edmodo" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory-external.vkpartner.ru/artifactory/maven"
        }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/yandexmobile/maven' }
        maven { url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android- 
minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/theartofdev/Edmodo" }
    }

}
rootProject.name = ""
include ':app'

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace 'com.qscan.qrscannerapp'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qscan.qrscannerapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1547
        versionName "4.5.2 release(4.5.2.1548)"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'livefriend'
            keyPassword 'dadada'
            storeFile file('C:\\android\\livefriend.jks')
            storePassword ''
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    repositories {



    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested

                // Forcing the version of android-image-cropper


                // Forcing version for Android Support libraries
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && 
!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '28.0.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:7.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
    implementation 'ru.rustore.sdk:billingclient:6.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
}


英語版でも質問中のようです。 how to solve "gradle failed resolve com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0"
